# Dropping Rows that Contain a Specific String wrapped in square brackets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm trying to drop rows which contain strings that are wrapped in a column. I want to drop all values that contain the strings '[removed]', '[deleted]'.
My df looks like this:

```
  Comments

1 The main thing is the price appreciation of the token (this determines the gains or losses more 
  than anything). Followed by the ecosystem for the liquid staking asset, the more opportunities 
  and protocols that accept the asset as collateral, the better. Finally, the yield for staking 
  comes into play.

2 [deleted]

3 [removed]

4 I could be totally wrong, but sounds like destroying an asset and claiming a loss, which I 
  believe is fraudulent. Like someone else said, get a tax guy - for this year anyway and then 
  you'll know for sure. Peace of mind has value too.
```

I have tried `df[df["Comments"].str.contains("removed")==False]`
But when i try to save the dataframe, it is still not removed.

EDIT:
My full code

```
import pandas as pd
sol2020 = pd.read_csv("Solana_2020_Comments_Time_Adjusted.csv")
sol2021 = pd.read_csv("Solana_2021_Comments_Time_Adjusted.csv")
df = pd.concat([sol2021, sol2020], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df[df["Comments"].str.contains("deleted")==False]
df[df["Comments"].str.contains("removed")==False]
```

Comment: can you provide your dataframe as DataFrame constructor or dictionary (df.to_dict())?

Comment: The df ive put in my question is a small part of a large dataframe that im using atm.

Comment: We need to see your code as well. It could be as simple as you expecting that `df` to be edited in place when it isn't.

Comment: I edit my post to add in my full code. im unsure as to why when i save the csv file, there seems to be no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

I have created a data frame for comments column and used my own comments but it should work for you

```
import pandas as pd

sample_data = { 'Comments': ['first comment whatever','[deleted]','[removed]','last comments whatever']}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

data = df[df["Comments"].str.contains("deleted|removed")==False]

print(data)
```

output I got

```
 Comments
0  first comment whatever
3  last comments whatever
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, has helped me massively

Comment: But @coder888  keep in mind that if any of the other comments happen to have `removed` or `deleted` in a sentence, they'll be removed as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
new_df = df[~(df['Comments'].str.startswith('[') & df['Comments'].str.endswith(']'))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                                            Comments
0  The main thing is the price appreciation of th...
3  I could be totally wrong, but sounds like dest...
```

That will remove all rows where the value of the `Comments` column for that row starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help with that, your solution along with the one above helped me massively